# How to get time length from now back to the start of today (00h:00p:00s) in angularjs

Tags: javascript

How to get timelength from now back to the start of today (00h:00p:00s) in angularjs?

```
ex: now is 13:45. So timelength = 13*60 + 45 mins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specificity in angular. Just use the `Date` object.

```
var date = new Date();
var timelength = date.getMinutes() + date.getHours() * 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a new JavaScript date object that represents the time now and then use the getHours and getMinutes functions to enable your calculation.

For example:

`var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();`

var timeLength = hours*60 + minutes;

Answer (score 0):

Converting a javascript date to a number gives you milliseconds since 1/1/1970 (UTC).  You can correct for your time zone if you wish, then just take the modulus of the number of milliseconds in a day to get the number of milliseconds since midnight:

```
var dt = new Date();
var num = dt - dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // offset is in minutes
var sec = num / 1000; // seconds
var sinceMidnight = sec % (24 * 60 * 60); // seconds since midnight
```